# Turning write-progress bar into GUI progress bar

Tags: user-interface, powershell

i am wondering how i can take my already functioning progress bar and turn it into a GUI that works with my function. Here is the code:

```
robocopy.exe $source $destination $files $backup $reportextrafiles $verboseoutput $fullpathname $mirror $backupmode $subfolders $Retries $consolewrite | ForEach-Object -Process {
    $data = $_.Split([char]9);
    if (($data.Count -gt 4) -and ("$($data[4])" -ne ""))
    {
        $file = "$($data[4])"
        Write-Progress "Percentage $($data[0])" -Activity "Documents" -CurrentOperation "$($file)" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue; 
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Progress "Percentage $($data[0])" -Activity "Documents" -CurrentOperation "$($file)"
    }
}
# Robocopy has a bitmask set of exit codes, so only complain about failures:
[int] $exitCode = $global:LastExitCode;
[int] $someCopyErrors = $exitCode -band 8;
[int] $seriousError = $exitCode -band 16;
if (($someCopyErrors -ne 0) -or ($seriousError -ne 0))
{
    Write-Error "ERROR: robocopy failed with a non-successful exit code: $exitCode"    
}
```

Can anyone guide me in the right direction in turning this into a proper GUI progress bar? Thanks!

Comment: Might I ask why? `Write-Progress` is (in my opinion) the "proper" way to do it. In a console host it will be textual, in ISE it will be graphical. What is your ultimate goal here?

Comment: My ultimate goal is for a WPF progress bar to pop up, so i can hide the behind PowerShell window.

Comment: If you mix what you have with this https://foxdeploy.com/2016/05/17/part-v-powershell-guis-responsive-apps-with-progress-bars/ you should be able to achieve what you want.

Comment: I have been looking at that, but i could not figure out how to incorporate that in to my script.